# Formatting using <iomanip> using C++ in Bloodshed

Tags: c++, formatting, iomanip

I have to rewrite fucntion p1() as p2() to mimic p1() exactly, using only `<iomanip>` and I keep getting errors that state

> invalid operands of types `long long unsigned int` and "unresolved function type" to binary `operator<<`

The code is here:

```
void p1()
{
    printf("Size of different basic C++ data type in number of bytes\n\n") ;
    printf("size of int           = %d \n", sizeof (int) ) ;
    printf("size of long          = %d \n", sizeof (long) ) ;
    printf("size of short         = %d \n", sizeof (short) ) ;
    printf("size of unsigned int  = %d \n", sizeof (unsigned int) ) ;
    printf("size of char          = %d \n", sizeof (char) ) ;
    printf("size of wchar_t       = %d \n", sizeof (wchar_t) ) ;
    printf("size of bool          = %d \n", sizeof (bool) ) ;
    printf("size of float         = %d \n", sizeof (float) ) ;
    printf("size of double        = %d \n", sizeof (double) ) ;
    printf("size of long double   = %d \n", sizeof (long double) ) ;
    printf("size of int ptr       = %d \n", sizeof (int *) ) ;
    printf("size of double ptr    = %d \n", sizeof (double *) ) ;
    printf("size of char ptr      = %d \n", sizeof (char *) ) ;
    printf("====================================\n\n") ;
}
```

Here is p2() where I have to use `<iomanip>`:

```
void p2()
{
    cout<<"Size of different basic C++ data type in number of bytes\n\n";  
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of int"<<"= %d" ,sizeof (int)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of long"<<"= %d" ,sizeof (long)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of short"<<"= %d", sizeof (short)<<endl ;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of unsigned int"<<"= %d", sizeof (unsigned int)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of char"<<"= %d", sizeof (char)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of wchar_t"<<"= %d", sizeof (wchar_t)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of bool"<<"= %d", sizeof (bool)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of float"<<"= %d", sizeof (float)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of double"<<"= %d", sizeof (double)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of long double"<<"= %d", sizeof (long double)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of int ptr"<<"= %d", sizeof (int *)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of double ptr"<<"= %d", sizeof (double *)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(10)<<"size of char ptr"<<"= %d", sizeof (char *)<<endl;
    cout<<setfill('=')<<setw(40)<<"="<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is why am I getting errors that state "invalid operands of types 'long long unsigned int' in p2()

Comment: `<<"= %d",` what do you think this should do? Just kick those parts!

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
cout<<setw(10)<<"size of int"<<"= %d" ,sizeof (int)<<endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
( (cout<<setw(10)<<"size of int"<<"= %d") , sizeof (int) ) << endl;
```

Note the comma there - it's acting as [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), discarding its left-hand argument and returning the right one. What you get is basically:

```
sizeof(int) << endl;
```

which clearly isn't valid. Also, `<< "= %d"` will just insert the string verbatim in the stream, nothing else. Format specifiers have no meaning here. When you stream using `operator<<`, overload resolution picks the correct overload automatically so the value being streamed is formatted correctly.

You need

```
cout << setw(10) << "size of int = " << sizeof(int) << endl;
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah :) Note to OP: the extra whitespace characters I added are optional but help readibility of the code a great deal.